# Formatting issues when unix file is sent to mail

Tags: email, unix, formatting, format

I have the following code to write data to a file called logdata.ext in a particular format.

```
echo "###############################################################################" >> logdata.txt
echo "                     HEADING GOES HERE                                         " >> logdata.txt
echo "###############################################################################" >> logdata.txt
echo " Server : $NAME       Time Stamp : $(date)" >> logdata.txt
echo " Mount Point                Disk Space Occupied             Action Required  " >> logdata.txt
echo "===============================================================================" >> logdata.txt
echo "ROOT_DIR                          $appl%                       $app_st" >> logdata.txt
echo "share                             $app_share%                      $share_st " >> logdata.txt
echo "/tmp                              $tmp%                        $tmp_st" >> logdata.txt
echo "/home                             $home%                       $home_st" >> logdata.txt
```

When I am opening the file using
           cat logdata.txt
I am getting the following well formatted output

> ```
> ###############################################################################
>                              HEADING GOES HERE
> ###############################################################################
>  Server : 198.168.53.45       Time Stamp : Wed Aug 12 06:41:48 PDT 2015
>  Mount Point                Disk Space Occupied             Action Required
> ===============================================================================
> ROOT_DIR                          64%                       No
> share                             94%                      Yes
> /tmp                              8%                        No
> /home                             69%                       No
> ```

But I tried sending the file logdata.txt to my email ID using the code

```
cat "logdata.txt" | mailx -s "Disk Space Warning!" myemail@mydomain.com
```

But the formatting was not as good as in the file.
I got it in the following format

```
###############################################################################
           HEADING GOES HERE                        
###############################################################################
 Server : 198.168.53.45  Time Stamp : Wed Aug 12 06:28:44 PDT 2015
 Mount Point      Disk Space Occupied      Action Required  
===============================================================================
ROOT_DIR               64%                       No
share          94%                      Yes 
/tmp                  8%                        No
/home                  69%                       No
```

Why am I getting a different format when I send the file to mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In command prompt or any editor program, text is displayed in monospaced/fixed width font, in which each character is of same horizontal width. However most likely, your mail client is using any other font (not monospaced) to display the text.

You can either attach the file with the mail, or use html to format the text.

Comment: So, isn't there any way to send that text so that at least the receiver of the mail will see it in proper formatting?

Comment: If you know the  recipient can view HTML emails, send it as HTML with the appropriate tags (`<html><body><pre>` etc). Better yet, send a `multipart/alternative` with the current content as `text/plain` and a HTML rendering as `text/html`. In the end, if the recipient can't configure their email client correctly, there isn't much you can do, though.